# Pivoting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have a table in **MySql** `tbl_Analysis` with following structure

```
uid | device_type
 1      Desktop
 2      Desktop
 3      Mobile
 4      Mobile
 5      Laptop
 6      Desktop
```

Now i need to get no. of users count group by `device_type`

I write the following query for this

```
select count(device_type) as count, 
device_type as device 
from tbl_Analysis 
group by device_type;
```

Following is result

```
count | device
 3       Desktop
 2       Mobile
 1       Laptop
```

Now I want these result to be `pivot`. In `Ms-Sql` there is built in functionality available but I could not find any way of doing this in MySQL.

My desired result is:

```
Desktop | Mobile | Laptop
3          2        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to generate the pivot view.

**Query**

```
select 
count(case when device_type = 'Desktop' then device_type end) as Desktop,
count(case when device_type = 'Mobile' then device_type end) as Mobile,
count(case when device_type = 'Laptop' then device_type end) as Laptop
from tb_analysis;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/486f3/3)

Another way to achieve this by dynamic sql.

**Query**

```
set @query = null;
select
group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'count(case when device_type = ''',
      device_type, ''' then device_type end) as ' ,device_type
    )
  ) into @query
from tb_analysis ;

set @query = concat('select ', @query, ' from tb_analysis
');

prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/486f3/4)

Comment: Can we get the result in more `dynamic` way i.e we don't know the actual `device_type` available in table.

Comment: Yes. I am just trying it out. please wait for some time